# How to left align bootstrap 3 dropdown menu?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]

In the above image MenuItems are align to right side of the MyMenu, I needed to left align the MenuItems of MyMenu (I mean it must aligned to left edge of MyMenu), I try to use pull-left and pull-right class like `<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-left" role="menu">` with my code, but it doesn't work. anyone has an idea how to do this ?

Here is my code

```
<!-- Static navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">

              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right text-uppercase">
                <li><a id="Home" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <!-- Visa drapdown-->
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> My Menu <span class="caret"></span></a>

                  <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-left" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Menu Item 01</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Menu Item 01</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Menu Item 02</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Menu Item 03</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Menu Item 04</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#"></a></li>

                    </ul>

                  </li>

            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
          </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Adding this style element to the dropdown `<ul>` will align the dropdown to the left side of the menu item:

```
left:0;
```

See this [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/pCZ6qhzkoZ) which targets the `.dropdown-menu.pull-left` and adds a `left:0;`.
This should solve your problem.

---

**Update**

I see that Bootstrap has [deprecated](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns-alignment) pull-right and pull-left as of Bootstrap 3.1.0. Use `dropdown-menu-left` class to use built-in Bootstrap css to align the dropdown on the left edge so you don't need extra CSS. See this updated [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/qCGdvJSIN8)

Comment: @Hanoncs Yeah this response is from last year, so it's possible that links get broken ... Moreover the whole bootply site doesn't load properly for me, so maybe they are just having some issues ...

Comment: Only about 7 months ago. Yeah hopefully their links font disappear like twitter. this is supposed to be a wiki basically.

Comment: @Hanoncs if we answer and link to external pages, like Bootply to illustrate a solution, we cannot guarantee for these links to stay working. The goal of Stackoverflow is not to be a wiki, we try to help each other with programming problems and questions. On topic, I get an application error, so I think the Bootply links will work again soon.

Comment: In case it's not obvious for everyone, both classes need to be added: `<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left">`.

Comment: @MondKin `<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left">` It doesn't work for Bootstrap 4

Answer (score 56):

### for Twitter Bootstrap 3

```
<div class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
    <!-- write your code here -->
</div>
```

hope it helps :)

Comment: on v. v3.3.1 not working

Answer (score 31):

For Bootstrap 3.1.0 or above use `.dropdown-menu-left` or `.dropdown-menu-right` to display the drop down menus right or left side of the parent menu. In your case try following.

```
 <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> My Menu <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left" role="menu">
       <!-- write your code here -->
      </ul>
 </li>
```

**Bootstrap is BEST**

Comment: This is the best solution 100%. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 16):

As the answers given above are too old, would like to provide working solution for Bootstrap 3.3.7.

[image]

Use the given css on your .dropdown-menu div :

```
.dropdown-left-manual {
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
  padding-left: 1px;
  padding-right: 1px;
}
```

Explaination :

- "right:0;" to make then ending of menu inline with end of dropdown
  button.
- "left:auto;" to override the left:0 given in dropdown-menu
  class by bootstrap.
- paddings are used to correct hovers on menu item, **can be ignored**.

Comment: @Aaron Any specific issue you are looking answers for in bootstrap 5.
You can ask. happy to help!

Answer (score 8):

Change navbar-right to navbar-left and add a pull-right class to the UL.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left text-uppercase pull-right">
```

Check out the JSfiddle for an example.

http://jsfiddle.net/eqcpLj6k/1/

Answer (score 2):

For **Bootstrap 4**:

There are CSS classes named: `.dropup`, `.dropright` and `.dropleft`.

```html
<div class="btn-group dropleft">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropleft
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <!-- Dropdown menu links -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Source: [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#dropleft-variation)

Answer (score 1):

For a dropdown item that has been floated to the right of the screen, with its dropdown content flowing over the screen, just add the below code to prevent the content of the dropdown from flowing over the screen.

```
right: 0;
```