# How to Float left the last subnav item of a bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to know how I can make the last item of a submenu, if it is larger than the container, be displayed to the left and not to the right.

**PS.: The solution of this question [How to left align bootstrap 3 dropdown menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27205687/how-to-left-align-bootstrap-3-dropdown-menu) is deprecated**

[image]

[Example jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tgkwpngw/)

```
        <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="/ambientes/" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Ambientes <b class="caret"></b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu">
            <a href="/ambientes/sala-de-estar" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Sala de Estar</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="/ambientes/sala-de-estar/conjunto-de-sofa">Conjunto de Sof&aacute;</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/ambientes/sala-de-estar/rack-com-painel">Rack com Painel</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/ambientes/sala-de-estar/sala-de-estar-completa">Sala de Estar Completa</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        ...
      </ul>
    </li>
```

Comment: @Praveen-Kumar The solution of this question How to left align bootstrap 3 dropdown menu? is deprecated

Comment: Deprecated? I don't get you.

Comment: In the solution it says that just use the class ".dropdown-menu-left" but this does not work. I may be wrong, but I tried here and it did not roll. If anyone can test the jsfiddle example I put there I would appreciate it.

Comment: Did you see the dupe I attached? That has the answer right? Did you try that?

Comment: :) I saw. But that's what I'm explaining ... In the solutions that are there, they do not solve my case ... In fact, not even the examples that are marked "solution" are working. Just click the link there to see that the example does not work.

Comment: OKay, then bear with me now. I am using a mobile connection. Will come soon and add an answer and solve it and open it too.

Comment: Opened it......

Comment: By deprecated @RodrigoDias means that the solution is not longer working on Bootsrap since it was updated. Sadly the Bootsrap documentation also states that this kind of problem may arise and has to be dealt with in a case to case fasion.
Do you really need the nav-bar to be aligned to the right ? 
Did you try the nav-bar-left  class?

Comment: Hi. Thanks guys...

So ... in my case the problem is the following: when the menu has the total size of the screen (100%) I needed that at least in the last item, the second level of the submenu would come to the left, as exemplified in the image attached